# Ansible not calling role

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am trying to run a playbook in ansible like this:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/inventory.yml playbook.yml -t my-role
```

**my-role -> main.yml**

```
- name: Start APP
  include_tasks: start-app.yml
  tags: my-role
```

**start-app.yml**

```
---
- name: Do something
  command: run_my_script.sh
  tags: my-role

- name: start my app now
  ansible.builtin.include_role:
    name: start-my-app
  register: result
  tags: my-role

- name: Print INFO
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: result
    verbosity: 1
  tags: my-role
```

When I try to run this I get no output so I tried do debug it and I get this:

```
TASK [start my app now] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [my-role : Print INFO] ********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": {
        "changed": false,
        "include_args": {
            "name": "start-my-app"
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that that its not executing the role start-my-app. Now sure why this is happening.
But the role start-my-app seems to work because it works if i run it like this:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/inventory.yml playbook.yml -t my-role
```

Any ideais why its not executing role start-my-app?

Comment: You're doing an `include_tasks`, not an `include_role`. So what should Ansible include?

Comment: yes, I am including some tasks inside start-app.yml but one of them is to run my role start-my-app. How can I do that?

Comment: You might want to look at [this crafted example](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/98ed5aaaab0f2ddc80d2728424117f8c) all together as what is expected as a [mre] and as what a basic correct role usage looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm betting the tasks in your `start-my-app` role don't have the `my-role` tag. Those tasks won't run with `ansible-playbook ... -t my-role`.

When using the dynamic *include_**, the included tasks don't inherit the tag.

```yaml
- name: start my app now
  ansible.builtin.include_role:
    name: start-my-app
  register: result
  tags: my-role  # This won't get inherited by the tasks in start-my-app
```

So you have 2 solutions:

1. Add `tags: my-role` to every task in `start-my-role`
2. Switch to using `import_role` instead of `include_role`, which will inherit the tags in the imported tasks. For more info about include vs import, check the docs [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest//playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse.html#comparing-includes-and-imports-dynamic-and-static-re-use).

Comment: If include is mandatory for dynamic reasons (e.g. loop), the good solution is actually missing: [using `apply` on the include task](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html#parameter-apply). Point 1 is a bad practice, especially for a role: e.g. restricting re-usability, too verbose, error prone (forgeting tag on new added tasks...). I'd personally not mention it as a solution but as something to definitely avoid. Meanwhile, note this is what OP has done. So knowing exactly what is wrong without a [mre] is actually a mentalist performance.

Comment: Monday I will try it and report back. Thanks. But yes the role start-my-app does not have the tag my-role. Is has a different role. So yes, I believe that might be the issue.